# How to access class data as if it were a dictionary

Tags: swift, class, dictionary

I am making my own class which stores information to do with a user. Just like the swiftyJSON framework, I would like to accsess the data as if the variable was a dictionary.

Example,

When using SwiftyJSON, you can run code as shown below:

```
let x = JSON["x"]
let y = JSON["y"].strVal
let x = JSON["z"].intVal
```

What I would loke to do is to have a class like the following below:

```
class User
{
    private (set) public var DATA:[String:Any]
    public init(){}
    public function login(username:String, password:String)
    {
        //Login code here
        self.DATA = loginResult
    }
}

let user = User()
user.login(username:"username", password:"password")
let name = user["name"].strVal
```

How would I be able to write this in swift?

Comment: Why? The benefit of classes is to access properties by name rather than (error-prone) key subscription with requires also cumbersome type casting and optional binding.

Comment: It's because my class is going to hold quite a lot of information and sometimes the keys may exist, other times they may not which means that they still need to be checked for anyway. Also, it's the learning process too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [`subscript`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html):

```
class User
{
    private (set) public var DATA:[String:Any]
    public init(){}
    public function login(username:String, password:String)
    {
        //Login code here
        self.DATA = loginResult
    }

    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        return DATA[key]
    }
}

let user = User()
user.login(username:"username", password:"password")
let name = user["name"].strVal
```

You probably want to store `DATA` as SwiftyJSON, so you can call `strVal`, etc. on it - just update the backing property and subscript signature as needed.